# Manually setting CPU's TSC value

Tags: performance, cpu, frequency

On my system **Ubuntu 16.04.1** with Kernel **4.13.0-36** the following TSC  frequency is detected:

```
dmesg | grep MHz:
```

`[    0.004000]         tsc: Detected 1800.000 MHz processor`

I have an **Intel i5-8250U KabyLake** CPU with a basefrequency of 1,6 GHz:

https://ark.intel.com/products/124967

The command `lscpu` shows:

```
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60GHz
Stepping:              10
CPU MHz:               1800.000
CPU max MHz:           1600,0000
CPU min MHz:           400,0000
BogoMIPS:              3600.00
```

If I fix the CPU frequency to 1.6 GHz and run

`watch -n1 cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy*/scaling_cur_freq`

I get frequencies close to 1.6GHz:

```
1600789
1600084
1599992
1600058
```

while another tool `cpufreq-aperf` at the same time shows:

```
000 1408000         00 sec 006 ms   00 sec 993 ms   00
001 1408000         00 sec 003 ms   00 sec 996 ms   00
002 1408000         00 sec 005 ms   00 sec 994 ms   00
003 1408000         00 sec 005 ms   00 sec 994 ms   00
```

Actually, I would not even care but I'm measuring the performance of some algorithms and this leads to wrong values:

- the C/B value of the algorithms is always higher by 11-13% to the known reference values
- Intel vTune tells me that my CPU Frequency Ratio is 0.886
- the percentual difference between the output of `cpufreq-aperf` and the content of `scaling_cur_frequency` is also ~ 88,6%

So I guess it's due to the wrong TSC value.

**Is there a way to manually set the detected TSC / CPU MHz value in Ubuntu?**

---

BTW, I guess its a bug/error caused by the hardware or by Intel, since Windows also reports the wrong base frequency in the TaskManager.

Comment: Well, no. The system figures out what tsc is during boot. In the source code tree see `arch/x86/kernel/tsc.c`. Your detail above is confusing, unless the reader also recalls your other question and reads it also. ... Oh, I see you deleted the other question, well explain what "C/B" is and that you have locked the CPU frequency and such.